# I cannot type the password in the PowerShell, it just doesn't type anything. What should I do?

Tags: ledger

The CLI after executing this .\monero-wallet-cli.exe --generate-from-device MoneroWallet --subaddress-lookahead 3:200 shows that I need to type a password but I can't type anything

Comment: what if you add in  --password <your password> on the command line?  On the linux/mac version typing in your password, the typing is hidden/invisible (not even *)